# EntitySqlException was unhandled by user code?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I get this error above when running my c# code:

```
'CategoryID' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly. Near simple identifier, line 6, column 1.
```

c#

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            foreach (Category category in GetCategories("", "CategoryID", "", 1, 10, 1))
            {
                //do something
            }

            return View();
        }


        public IQueryable<Category> GetCategories(string filterExpression, string sortExpression, string sortDirection, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int pagesCount)
        {
            NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterExpression))
                return db.Categories.OrderBy(sortExpression + " " + sortDirection).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            else
                return db.Categories.OrderBy(sortExpression + " " + sortDirection).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pagesCount * pageSize);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use ESQL you must use entity alias for accessing properties. Default alias is `it` so you must use `"it.CategoryID"`.